# InvocableMethod not appearing in Cloud Flow designer

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have written an `@InvocableMethod`, with an `@IncovableVariable` as such:

```
public class SimpleAccountLookup {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<Account> getAccountId(List<GetAccountActionRequest> requestDetails) {
        System.debug(requestDetails);
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account
                              WHERE A_Custom_Field__c = :requestDetails.get(0).thatFieldValue
                              LIMIT 10];
        return accounts;
    }

    public class GetAccountActionRequest {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String thatFieldValue;
    }

}
```

Which all seems like legit Apex to me, and it saves and complies just fine.

However, when I go to my Flow builder, it isn't appearing in the list of Apex options as I would expect.

[image: No method in Apex]

There are three other Apex methods in there (created by other developers) which are almost identical in composition... but mine is not there. I have waited a couple of hours - as I know sometimes these things take weirdly long in Salesforce (like Lightning Components appearing in the App builder), but it's just not there. Any one have any thoughts, tips, places to check, or other things I need to update?

This is just in a straight up sandbox, no managed package, domain, namespace.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and in my DE org it juts works fine .Weird ! Sounds like a bug to me at first glance

Comment: Same worked for me, maybe try changing the `version` of apex class!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava ... driven by your comment, I just copied and pasted the code from my Apex class into a "new" class, and gave it a different name - and it has appeared straight up. The "original" is still absent though. Other than class name there is *no* difference between them. That is so odd (and Rahul - they are both the same version!!) *strange*

Comment: Thank you both for your efforts and input though. +1

Comment: I have seen this before, you may need to run tests on the invocable class to get SFDC to recognize it as "available"